# Access 2013: Saving multiple page PDF from single report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've never posted before and am new to this.  I'm using VBA to get a single report to save multiple PDFs.  I receive an "Object missing" error message from the code I built from some of the postings here or other sites.  I have tried multiple corrections, but each results in either this or a new error.  The code is:

```
Private Sub RunErrors55COPY_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_RunErrors55_Click

Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFilename As String
Dim uniqueID As Recordset
Dim Report_ID As Field
Dim Db As Database
MyPath = "\\test.net\files\bissvcs\Services\Errors\"

Set Db = CurrentDb()
Set uniqueID = Db.OpenRecordset("ReportIdent01")

'Loop structure may vary depending on how you obtain values
For Each uniqueID In Report_ID
    MyFilename = "Bsvc Error " & Report_ID & ".pdf"
'Open report preview and auto-save it as a PDF
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Report01 Error Check", acViewPreview, , "uniqueID = " & Report_ID
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Report01 Error Check", acFormatPDF, MyPath & MyFilename, False
'Close the previewed report
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "Report01 Error Check"
Next uniqueID

Exit_RunErrors55_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_RunErrors55_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_RunErrors55_Click

End Sub
```

Any ideas and help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It would help to include what the above code is doing differently from what you want.  Which part are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: Brian, you probably want to [merge your two accounts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Error handling `MsgBox Err.Description` is a good start, but not sufficient.  A displayed error should compel you to trace through the code line by line--or place other error handling code--to locate the exact line of the error and what object is the source of the problem. Use breakpoints and/or the naked `Resume` keyword to get you to the very specific line. You might find that nothing is wrong with your VBA code, rather an error from the report itself, maybe from a specific `uniqueID` value. If "multiple corrections" just lead to more errors, then you're not understanding the errors.

Comment: At the least when asking for help, you should post complete error information including `Err.Number` and what line(s) caused the problem.  Observe if the error happens immediately, or only for certain iterations of the loop. Consider temporarily disabling (i.e. comment out) `On Error GoTo Err_RunErrors55_Click` line so that Access will let you debug starting from exactly where and when the error occurs. Use the variable watch pane and immediate window to get more information.  If these steps don't help you fix the bug yourself, then update the question with the information you gather.

Comment: We're missing some essential information. `For Each uniqueID In Report_ID` should actually iterate through all the IDs, probably using a recordset. Please provide the underlying table name and structure, then I can answer this.